# Equivalence of functions of random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, density-function

I've come across the following claim regarding equivalence of functions of random variables, and I need help verifying whether this claim is true or not:

- We are given the following function of random variable $X$:

  $$G(X) = X - ln(X)$$

  where $E(X) > 1$. Observe that $G(X)$ is also a monotonically increasing function for $X >= 1$.

Now the claim is that due to the aforementioned properties, $G(X)$ is equivalent to $F(X) = X$.

I fail to see how this claim is possible, unless perhaps $G(X)$ and $F(X)$ are equivalent in distribution, but that too is difficult to see. I will note that in practical applications, we are concerned only in the tails of distributions of $G(X)$ and $F(X)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more context.  There are lots of different equivalence  relations, and it's not at all clear what is meant here. Where does this occur?

Comment: In statistical hypothesis testing. $G(X)$ and $F(X)$, which is simply equal to $X$, are random variables representing likelihood ratios derived from different assumptions about the data. The claim is trying to show that the two likelihood ratios are somehow equal.

Comment: What if I were to re-state the question as,  could $G(X)$ be equal in distribution to $X$
 given that the expectation of $X$ is always greater than 1 and $G(X)$ is monotonically increasing for $X$ greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: If $X > 1$, then since $G(X) = X - \ln(X) < X$ it is impossible that $G(X)$ and $X$ have the same distiribution.  I suppose you might contrive an example that uses the fact that $G(X) \to +\infty$ as $X \to 0+$ to make them equal, but it's certainly not the case in general.

Comment: I will have to ask the person making the claim to provide more details (the person will be difficult to reach for sometime, which is why I asked the question here).

Note that the property is $E(X) > 1$, and not $X >1$. I agree that it seems that the claim is not valid in general.

Answer (score 2):

The only case where $X$ and $Y=G(X)$ have the same distribution is the trivial one $X = 1$ almost surely. This is ruled out by your condition $\mathbb E[X] > 1$.

Let $G(x) = x - \ln(x)$.  Suppose $X$ is a random variable with $X > 0$ a.s.,
and $Y = G(X)$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Note that $G$ is a strictly convex function with $G(1) = 0$ and $G'(1) = 0$, so $G$ has a strict minimum at $1$, i.e. $G(x) \ge 1$ for all $x > 0$, with equality only at $x=1$.  Since $Y \ge 1$ a.s., if its distribution is the same as that of $X$, we also have $X \ge 1$ a.s.  But then $Y \le X$ a.s., with $Y < X$ whenever $X > 1$, so the only way $X$ and $Y$ can have the same distribution is that $X = 1$ a.s.